# Why do we use empty while (1) at the end of embedded c programs?

Tags: c, while-loop, embedded-linux

I was wondering as why do we include an empty while(1) loop in the end of most c programs for example motor driver, gyro sensor routines? I searched but didn't find any satisfactory reason for this.

Thanks.

For example following code on an ATmega8:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
void main (void)
{
int n = 1;
DDRB = 0xFF;
for (n=1; n<=10; ++n)
{
PORTB = 0x00;
_delay_ms(1000);
PORTB = 0XFF;
}
while (1)
{}
}
```

Comment: Who is 'we'? Could you give an example maybe?

Comment: I've worked with embedded C/C++ programming for 8 years and have never seen this. Is it typically in smaller systems running on a light weight HW?

Comment: @scy7he - it's not uncommon on such systems, but is often a bad idea since it wastes a large stack.

Comment: @MartinJames - this should not waste stack at all.

Comment: Pardon my editing, i am new to this forum.

Comment: Thanks all for clearing it out so nicely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many embedded systems use timers, interrupts or other events to drive their actions.  They may also run OS's that provide threads or tasks that might be set up to performer he real work.  So once that initialization is done, there's nothing left for the `main()` program to do, but in such simple systems there is often nothing for `main()` to return to, so an infinite do nothing loop keeps the processor busy while nothing else is happening.

Comment: While(true), if there is an RTOS involved a simple while(1){} loop is a waste of stack, even if main() is used as an idle task and so CPU waste is OK. main() typically has a large stack since it's used for initialization in crt and static ctors, so it's better used for some actual work and another thread raised to be an idle task.  I use main() to run the SD-card driver which needs a big stack, and an idle thread that flashes an LED with a sleep() loop and puts the processor into a 'wait for interrupt' low-power mode.

Answer (score 0):

An empty while(1) loop prevents the thread from exiting.  Perhaps that's what's desired by the code you are looking at.

Comment: Indeed, in a minimal environment, having main() return can be a very bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Even in simple programs, an implementation is free to

- restart (reset)
- or hang

at the end of `main()`.

You can enforce the latter behaviour by this endless loop.

If you want the program to repeat endlessly, you can as well do so.

If you don't exactly know what the library does upon return from `main()`, you better don't return, but loop the one or other way.